# vue.js pass function to component as prop

Tags: vue.js, components

i'am trying to pass function to component
html

```
<v-select :options="[
              {label:'ll', value:'vv'},
              {label:'ll', value:'vv'},
              {label:'ll', value:'vv'},
              {label:'ll', value:'vv'},
            ]" :s_onchange="doo()"   ></v-select>
```

Vue.js

```
let myVue = new Vue({
    el:'#myVue',
    data:{ 
    },  
    methods:{
          doo(){
             console.log('doo');
          }
  }//End methods
});
```

component code

```
<template>
     <div>
         <p> some text </p>
     </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default { s_onchange: Function },
    mounted() {
         this.s_onchange()
}
</script>
```

the problem is this.s_onchange is not a function
if find a solution is
in Vue.js

```
doo(){
    return function (){
           console.log('doo');
      } 
}
```

is there anyway else to get rid of return function

Answer (score 0):

Change your binding expression from

```vue
:s_onchange="doo()"
```

to

```vue
:s_onchange="doo"
```

`doo()` will call the function straight away at binding time and pass the result of that call to the `s_onchange` prop, whereas `doo` simply passes the function instance itself.

I should also mention, this situation should make use of events instead of passing a function with a prop (unless you have some specific reason why you require a function prop instead of an event).

Comment: doo doesn't work , unfortunately i have  specific reasons for prop

Comment: It should work, some other code not provided in the question must be the culprit. Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: doo  work like doo() 
stil need to return function 
i deleted the rest of the code just for test